# relative element in flex-box , losing the width

Tags: html, css

I have a relative element within which there is an element with an image background that is absolute, when the parent of the relative element becomes a flex-box I lose the width, only when I bring the relative element static width (width: num px), I do not lose the width but the image does not responsive.

```css
  /* -------------------------------- */
  /* header */
  header {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    display:flex;
  }
  .header-items h1 {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
  }
  .header-items p {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .pre--order {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    margin-bottom: 64px;
  }
  .pre--order a {
    padding: 16px 26px;
    background-color: #f16718;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-right: 32px;
  }
  .pre--order p {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .keyboard--header {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 425px;
  }
  .kh--image {
    background-image: url("https://www.beauchamp.com/_wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/xIsrael_TelAviv_City_shai-pal1.jpg");
    background-repeat: unset;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: 0;
    left: 24px;
  }
```

```html
  <header>
      <div class="container">
      <section class="header-items">
        <h1>Typemaster Keyboard</h1>
        <p>
          Improve your productivity and gaming without breaking the bank.
          Upgrade to a high quality mechanical typing experience.
        </p>
        <div class="pre--order">
          <a href="#">Pre-order now</a>
          <p>Release on 5/27</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="keyboard--header">
          <div class="kh--image"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: make a snippet with the HTML and CSS

Comment: I did that right now

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I losing the width of the relative element ( .keyboard--header )  when is parents become flex-box , i can set static width but than i lose the Responsiveness of the image .

Comment: You can't use position absolutes & relatives and expect to easily make a responsive website! Can you edit your question to explain what you want the background to do, maybe an image of the desired outcome, looking through your code now

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I've wrapped the flexbox, given the flex child an explicit width&height, and fixed up a bunch of things like margin/padding you should generally base off typography not px

```css
header {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.header-items h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.header-items p {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.pre--order {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.pre--order a {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  background-color: #f16718;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 2em;
}

.pre--order p {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.keyboard--header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.kh--image {
  background-image: url("https://www.beauchamp.com/_wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/xIsrael_TelAviv_City_shai-pal1.jpg");
  background-clip: cover;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="header-items">
      <h1>Typemaster Keyboard</h1>
      <p>
        Improve your productivity and gaming without breaking the bank. Upgrade to a high quality mechanical typing experience.
      </p>
      <div class="pre--order">
        <a href="#">Pre-order now</a>
        <p>Release on 5/27</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="keyboard--header">
    <div class="kh--image"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```